# Any potential issues with using "Netty 4.1.8.Final" in "WildFly 10.1.0.Final"?

Tags: netty, wildfly

"WildFly 10.1.0.Final" includes "Netty to 4.0.33.Final". But I want to use the latest "Netty 4.1.8.Final". I am wondering if there are any potential issues.

I appreciate any comments/feedback.

Comment: This really falls under the "Try it and See" (TIAS) mantra. The best kind of question for SO would be if you had tried it, and ran into problems, and were asking a specific question about solving that problem.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you bundle in your app, you will be fine.

Otherwise see my response on developer.jboss.org [forum](https://developer.jboss.org/message/969349#969349)